# No able to download images from my APP

Tags: blackberry

I'm doing an app for saudi client.My problem is i'm not able to download images at client location.The same code is working out perfectly in my location(India).The only positive thing is XMLs are downloaded at client location.

My Code is like :

`HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(serverUrl+suffix);
c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/png");`

if (c.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
   is = c.openInputStream();
}else{
    return null;
}

Please suggest me any solns.

Thanks & Regards,

Sree Harsha.P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Solved.
The code i changed is i returned EncodedImage instead of inputstream from method.

But don't know why returning InputStream from method  worked in india and doesn't work in saudi

```
        c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(serverUrl+suffix);
        c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/png");
        if (c.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            is = c.openInputStream();
            Constants.connectionLength = c.getLength();
            int c1;
            StringBuffer sb =new StringBuffer();
            while( (c1 = is.read()) != -1){
                sb.append((char)c1);
            }

            byte [] b = sb.toString().getBytes();
            EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
            return encodedImage;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
```